# Update to AngularJS 1.5.9 broke Angular Route

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular app that I had to update to 1.5.9 recently.

In my app it's necessary for someone to get an URL (eg.: http://somedomain/#/dashboard/1) and have a direct access to that screen, which is quite common.

In the latest version this worked perfectly, but now with 1.5.9 angular always redirects this request to the root path (http://somedomain/#/), causing all links to be broken.

How do I fix this? Is this some new rule, or a bug with this version, or some configuration I have to change?

**--- UPDATE ---**

My router code is a little confusing because I have several modules, and each one defines an object like this:

```
portal._routes = {
    '/': {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/layout/controller/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/layout/template/home.html'
    },
    '/application': {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/layout/controller/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/layout/template/home.html'
    },
    '/dashboard': {
        controller: 'DashboardListController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/dashboard/controller/dashboard-list',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/dashboard/template/dashboard-list.html'
    },
    '/dashboard/new': {
        controller: 'DashboardFormController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/dashboard/controller/dashboard-form',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/dashboard/template/dashboard-form.html'
    },
    '/dashboard/:id': {
        controller: 'DashboardViewController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/dashboard/controller/dashboard-view',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/dashboard/template/dashboard-view.html'
    },
    '/dashboard/public/:id': {
        controller: 'PublicDashboardViewController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/dashboard/controller/dashboard-view-public',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/dashboard/template/dashboard-view-public.html'
    },
    '/dashboard/:id/edit': {
        controller: 'DashboardFormController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/dashboard/controller/dashboard-form',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/dashboard/template/dashboard-form.html'
    },
    '/user/form': {
        controller: 'UserFormController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/user/controller/user-form',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/user/template/user-form.html'
    },
    '/user/new': {
        controller: 'UserFormController',
        controllerUrl: 'portal/user/controller/user-form',
        templateUrl: 'app/portal/user/template/user-form.html'
    }
};
```

Then I have this in the main angular module file:

```
connecta.config(function ($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $provide, $filterProvider, $translateProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider, $sceProvider, applications) {
    configureLazyProviders($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $provide, $filterProvider);
    configureTranslations($translateProvider, window.navigator);
    configureRoutes($routeProvider);
    configureRequestInterceptors($httpProvider, applications);
    configureHTTPWhitelist($compileProvider, $sceProvider);

    configureAuthenticationListener($httpProvider, $routeProvider);
});
```

Which calls this `configureRoutes` function:

```
function configureRoutes($routeProvider) {
    var allRoutes = buildRoutes(portal, presenter, maps);
    angular.forEach(allRoutes, function (route, url) {
        if (route.controllerUrl) {
            if (!route.resolve) {
                route.resolve = {};
            }

            if (!route.resolve.load) {
                route.resolve.load = function ($q, $rootScope) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    require([route.controllerUrl], function () {
                        deferred.resolve();
                        $rootScope.$apply();
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
            }
        }
        $routeProvider.when(url, route);
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        template: '<h1>Not Found</h1>'
    });
}
```

Which calls this auxiliary `buildRoutes` function:

```
function buildRoutes() {
    var finalRouteObject = {};
    angular.forEach(arguments, function (module) {
        // Coloca a referência
        angular.forEach(module._routes, function (value) {
            value.module = module.name;
        });

        $.extend(true, finalRouteObject, module._routes);
    });
    return finalRouteObject;
}
```

This code was working and has not been changed recently, only Angular has been updated and it does this weird redirect to the root path.

Comment: it's impossible to know why your routes aren't working without seeing your route code.

Comment: @Claies added more info